# Set column width of table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap 3.7 for my project and I came to a point where I'd want to create a table whose first row has a predefined width.

What I have tried was using the style="width:100px" as shown below:

```
<thead>
    <tr id="header">
        <th data-width="100px"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: What you have written in description and in code is totally different.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be with style attribute as

```
<th style="width: 100px;"></th>
```

OR

```
<th width="100px"></th>
```